# Does Altair have any sort of query builder than can generate vega.js code or something that can end up in a front end?

Tags: python, altair

This is altair. https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html

You can generate vega specs from python. Is there a way to generate query widget specs too? My understanding is that the ipywidget stuff in altair is only for notebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See [Input Element Binding](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#input-element-binding) in the Altair documentation.

For a worked example, see [US Population Over Time](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/us_population_over_time.html):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

pink_blue = alt.Scale(domain=('Male', 'Female'),
                      range=["steelblue", "salmon"])

slider = alt.binding_range(min=1900, max=2000, step=10)
select_year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['year'],
                                   bind=slider, init={'year': 2000})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sex:N', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('people:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 12000000))),
    color=alt.Color('sex:N', scale=pink_blue),
    column='age:O'
).properties(
    width=20
).add_selection(
    select_year
).transform_calculate(
    "sex", alt.expr.if_(alt.datum.sex == 1, "Male", "Female")
).transform_filter(
    select_year
).configure_facet(
    spacing=8
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have been specific. I am looking for query-side (backend) filters. My understanding is that transforms are aimed at transforming client data. I'm imagining that simply change the data url to a PUT request and sending the transform spec could be a good approach here. Are there any examples you are aware of doing this? Or perhaps another way that I've missed?

Comment: I guess this might be relevant: https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/912

Comment: And the dynamic data loading in vega might be the hook, will look for that in altair:

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/data/

https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/master/docs/docs/data.md#dynamic-data-loading

Comment: No, Altair doesn’t provide anything like that.

Comment: If I get somewhere with the vega side of it, I think I see a path to kind of specing out the widgets in altair (on fixed data) and then doing some minor mod on the vega side. Probably not a bad workflow. Will try to post some notes if I get there.